# Highlight a cell if a referenced cell is today's month/day (not year)

Tags: date, google-sheets, reference, highlight, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to use Google Sheets to highlight a student's name if their birthday is today. I have Column A with student's name and a column D with student's birthdate containing the year. I need to highlight the cell that contains their name if it is their birthday today.

I have found Conditional Formatting formulas that show me if it is their birthday month, and those that show me if they were born today, but I do not want to include the year, and I want it to be for only today. I have tried to tinker with these formulas for a couple of hours to make one suit my needs, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula to highlight dates that match today's month and day.

```
IF(AND(MONTH(B1)=MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(B1)=DAY(TODAY())),TRUE,FALSE)
```

For anyone looking for where to apply this formula for conditional formmating purposes, do the following:

In your sheet, select the column or range of cells you want to format, then go to Format > Conditional formatting, and choose "Custom formula is" from the "Format cells if..." menu to set your formula (then choose the other formatting options you want).

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

To add to your comment, you will need to add "$" before your reference cell to make this work.

IF(AND(MONTH($B1)=MONTH(TODAY()),DAY($B1)=DAY(TODAY())),TRUE,FALSE)